# Free and fast NAS software for arm

Tags: debian, networking, storage

I own a bananapro computer and I want to set up a NAS on it. I have already tried samba, but I don't like it very much. Is there alternative software for Debian, that would work with Mac? Windows compatibility would be nice as well, but not needed.
I'd also like to keep the Debian, that is installed there, if possible.

Comment: Maybe search for FreeNAS. It us based on BSD but a great NAS OS.

Comment: FreeBSD is lacking into support of ARM devices, much less having FreeNAS for that.

Comment: I have looked at those dedicated nas OSes, but I didn't find any, that would be arm compatible

Answer (score 1):

The Unix and Linux `NFS` (Network File System) works with all Unix and Linux systems, including `Mac OS X` and is the native method of sharing file systems between Unix and Linux systems.

The common procedure of setting up `NFS` on Debian is well documented and well known.

Mac OS X contains GUI tools for mounting remote `NFS` directories, as well as the full suite of native `NFS` administrative command line utilities.

`NFS` clients exist for Windows, but you may want to consider temporarily enabling Samba in the event you have a Windows client.

References:

[The Debian Administrator's Handbook, *Section 11.4. NFS File Server*](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.nfs-file-server.en.html)

[Debian Wiki *NFS Server Setup* page](https://wiki.debian.org/NFSServerSetup).

[Apple Technical Whitepaper *Autofs: Automatically Mounting Network File Shares in Mac OS X*](http://www.apple.com/business/docs/Autofs.pdf)

[serverfault.com Question: Are there any free NFS clients for Windows 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/190020/are-there-any-free-nfs-clients-for-windows-7)